# How to open a javascript three level collapsible menu on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fairly new to coding with javascript; I want to have a three-level collapsible menu, which will expand when clicked. I have written some code but it only works for a two-level menu only. I cannot work out how to alter the script so that the third level will open when clicked too. Any ideas would be most appreciated and do not prefer to use jquery and so if any suggestions with vanilla js would be really helpful for me!

Here is the existing script:

```
var openListItem=document.getElementsByClassName("nav-links-item");
var i;
for(i = 0; i < openListItem.length; i++){
    openListItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
        var items=this.children;
        items[2].classList.add("active");
        for (var j = 1; j < i; j++){
            var nestedItems = (this.children[2].children[j].children[2]);
            nestedItems[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                this.classList.add("active")
            });
        }
        console.log(j,nestedItems);
    });
}
```

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuneatrq/2/)**

I want to click on menu items and it should add an active class to the the items I click and the navigation menu is of three layers.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thank you all :)

Comment: Just fyi... your JsFiddle is broken.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Good to hear you are learning JS. Let me try to help you out.
You are in the right direction, as far as I can tell from your code.

It seems you are making multiple selections of first the `.nav-links-item` elements and then a specific set of children. This seems complicated and easy to lose track over. Let's make it a bit easier.

I noticed in your fiddle that you added the `.open-link` class on some of the `<li>` elements. I assume that this is because you want those elements to open and show their submenu. That is a good usage of a class, because it gives a clear understanding of what might be going on. Let's use that!

Select all the elements you want to respond on a click, in this case the `.open-link` elements, and set the active class to those elements when they are clicked.

```
var openListItems = document.getElementsByClassName("open-link");

function onListItemClick(event) {
    this.classList.add('active');
    event.preventDefault();
}

var i = 0;
for(i; i < openListItems.length; i++) {
    openListItems[i].addEventListener('click', onListItemClick);
}
```

Now every time you click a `.open-link` element it will get the `.active` class. So now you can define in your CSS that whenever a `.open-link` has become `.open-link.active` it needs to show the next level `<ul>` inside it. Something like so:

```
.open-link > ul {
    display: none;
}

.open-link.active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Notice the `>` in the CSS selector. This is important to make sure that not every `ul` in `.open-link` is shown, but only the one that is a direct child of `.open-link`.

[Here is a fiddle with a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/swxn7juz/)

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you Emiel for your answer :). I will give your code a try but I have a  small question regarding the css you suggested, inside the ul , I have svg, span tags and li elements and only want to grab the li elements and so the > selector will grab the li or only the direct first child of ul? Thanks  for your help again bro :)

Comment: The `>` will select the `<ul>` that is directly inside `.open-link`. Without it you would select all of the `<ul>` tags inside the `.open-link` element and show all of them when the active class is added. And since you want to build levels of hierarchy, this seem like the way to go :). The `<svg>`, `<span>` and `<li>` tags will not be affected. I've added a JSFiddle for you to examine.

Comment: To add on this. It is easier to add a class to a `<ul>` with all the items inside of it then selecting all `<li>` inside a `<ul>` and adding a class to every single on of them. Keep that in mind! ;)

Comment: Thanks Emiel for your inputs.It was really helpful :)

Comment: I tried but since I do not have 15 reputation points I am not allowed to give a up vote for the answer